# Would a recruiter contact me after messing up a technical test?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, test

I have applied for a job, and while I already have good experience, I have messed up the pre-interview technical test. This is the first job I have applied for that gave a technical test, so I might have been a bit nervous, so that led to me forgetting simple things that usually I don't while already working.

Are these tests usually a deciding factor, so that if you mess it up you usually don't get to the interview? It could be that they are done as an early indicator, but I am not completely sure about it.

I'm not asking about that specific company, but I want to know more about the likely interpretations of technical test results.

Comment: This is pretty open ended and varies heavily from person to person.  If possible, try rephrasing the question into something more direct.

Comment: Yes, as this is currently phrased this is really opinion-based and even company specific. Would you ming rephrasing it so your post is not closed?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Mon'em if you want check [this link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to know what you should avoid asking

Comment: @DarkCygnus thank you. I have edited it, can you please re-read it and see if it still needs more rephrasing?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Mon'em I think that it is still a *bit* opinion-based. We could give you our point of view and what *we* would do, but those recruiters can have a completely different opinion on how to take this. I'll take a shot at editing, but I fear that without a proper rewording this might get closed.

Comment: Do you remember the technical test (roughly)? Do you remember your answer? What kind of job were you applying for? Without this information, we can't really tell you. Don't get hangup on just one employer. Apply to as many as you can.

Comment: If the test results did not matter to them then they would not assign the test.

Comment: Interview processes are typically stage-based, with every stage ending with a proceed / don't proceed decision. But the test may also not be considered a stage, but instead a part of the interview, where you'll discuss your results (even if they're not good). They may also look at your answers instead of, or in addition to, just your final score, or more difficult questions may be more heavily weighted. Or they're trying out the test and don't yet take the results too seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a technical test is given pre-interview it is often being used to narrow down the list of candidates to those that they wish to interview (it's how I do it when recruiting developers - check they have the baseline skills to do the job and then check "fit" for the job at interview) so a poor performance on such a test may well scupper any chances of getting to the interview stage.

I wouldn't lose hope just yet though.. not every company will cull candidates at this stage and even those that do may still interview you as it depends not only on how you performed on the test but also how the other candidates did and it is very easy to fall into the trap of thinking you did worse that is actually the case - especially when you are unfamiliar with this sort of test.

At this stage all you can really do is carry on with your job hunt as before and if they get back to you they get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. I will continue my job searching process as normal and see where this goes.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how far along you are in the interview process:

A failure very early in the interview process, before you really got a chance to really interview with someone would most likely be the end for you.

If however, you took the test in-person during an actual interview, and were able to discuss with the interviewer the questions you have wrong, there may be some hope depending on your responses.

Comment: This is exactly my experience.  It is very rare to fail a test and get the job.

Comment: While I agree with what you are saying, you may have missed the fact that the OP specifically refers to this as being a **pre**-interview technical test.

Comment: @motosubatsu While I agree with your agreement :), in this case, I think the answer is fine. The first 2 paragraphs answer the question, the 3rd paragraph is "additional information".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was before the interview itself, which I’m still waiting to see if they’ll call me for or not. I’ll continue searching, as @motosubatsu suggested below, this is the best I can do now.